# Disk Space full while doing apt-get operation on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, ubuntu-14.04, disk-space-utilization

Im Trying to install new software on my Ubuntu 14.04, which is running

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-45-generic
```

There are old kernals installed on my machine

```
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic       3.13.0-24.47                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic       3.13.0-45.74                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic       3.13.0-55.94                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic       3.13.0-57.95                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic       3.13.0-58.97                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic       3.13.0-59.98                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic       3.13.0-61.100                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic 3.13.0-24.47                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic 3.13.0-45.74                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic 3.13.0-55.94                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic 3.13.0-57.95                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic 3.13.0-58.97                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-59-generic 3.13.0-59.98                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-61-generic 3.13.0-61.100                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic 3.13.0-62.102                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic                 3.13.0.62.69                     amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

When i am trying to Purge them using below command

```
$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Im getting above error.

While doing auto remove getting error

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

And if i run force install it is saying no space left on device ..

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-55 linux-headers-3.13.0-55-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-57 linux-headers-3.13.0-57-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-58 linux-headers-3.13.0-58-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-59 linux-headers-3.13.0-59-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-59-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-3.13.0 linux-source-3.13.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 48 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 15.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 42.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirrors.voxel.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic amd64 3.13.0-62.102 [15.2 MB]
Fetched 15.2 MB in 4s (3,237 kB/s)                        
(Reading database ... 243451 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic_3.13.0-62.102_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic (3.13.0-62.102) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic_3.13.0-62.102_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-62-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-62-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic_3.13.0-62.102_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My disk utilisation:

```
$ df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3      955997652 5241596 911812456   1% /
none                   4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             4066160      12   4066148   1% /dev
tmpfs             815404     512    814892   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             4077016       0   4077016   0% /run/shm
none              102400       0    102400   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1         190346  152098     24199  87% /boot
```

How can i make space on my Ubuntu so that i can install new applications on it ?

Please help...

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

Answer (score 4):

You're right, you have plenty of disk space on `/` but you quickly fill up `/boot` when you try to unpack the new image, which is why your `apt-get install -f` command fails.

The problematic packages are in your `dpkg` output, and the `apt-get` output.

You can try using `aptitude install -f` to see if one of the choices will resolve the issue for you (probably by removing those packages), or you can try `apt-get purge linux-image-extra-3.13.0-61-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic linux-image-generic`
to remove the broken, and partially configured packages installed.

If you're desperate enough to use `dpkg` be sure to pay attention to the messages and remove dependencies on a package before trying to remove a package. From your command above, you should probably remove `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic` before trying to remove `linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic` if you want to go that route.

Take extra care to make sure you don't remove the running kernel `3.13.0-45-generic`.

Then you can `apt-get autoremove` and `apt-get purge` the remaining unneeded kernel packages, and then install the later kernel it looks like you were trying to install.

Answer (score 1):

Your root file system (`/`) has plenty of free space, however `/boot` does not.

Take a closer look at the error output from the `sudo apt-get install -f` command:

```
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic (3.13.0-62.102) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic_3.13.0-62.102_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
```

It's trying to place a file in `/boot` and that file system doesn't have enough space for it.

Your options:

1. Remove files from `/boot` that are no longer needed
2. Add more space to `/boot`.  This one may be difficult to do since LVM isn't being used.  If this is a virtual machine perhaps not.
3. Ditch `/boot` altogether.  In most situations having a separate file system for `/boot` isn't necessary. ([before considering this take a look at @Kassandry's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/718476/disk-space-full-while-doing-apt-get-operation-on-ubuntu-14-04/718486#718486))

If you decide to get rid of the `/boot` file system you can do the following.

**NOTE: Be very careful if you use the following instructions**:

```
mkdir ~/copy-of-boot-files
sudo rsync -aHS /boot/ ~/copy-of-boot-files/
sudo umount /boot
sudo rsync -AHS ~/copy-of-boot-files/ /boot/
sudo sed -i 's/.*\/boot.*/#&/' /etc/fstab
```

**Again: be very careful if you do this**.  Make sure you have Ubuntu installation media around so you can boot into Linux Rescue mode to repair any damage you may cause.  **You could render your system unbootable if this isn't done properly**.

Basically you'd create a copy of `/boot`'s contents, unmount /boot, copy the contents back, and disable `/boot` from being mounted during start up.

**An additional note**:  You may need to update your bootloader configuration (e.g. `update-grub`, not sure what that version of Ubuntu uses).  Also, if this is a paravirtualised guest under Xen you need to make sure the domU configuration knows to retrieve the kernel from the new location (`sda3` instead of `sda1`).